# When using tensorflow' fit_generator method I get a weird error after the first two batches are correclty yielded

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with tensorflow 1.8.0. When I use the `fit_generator` method, I get the following error, even though the first two batches are yielded correctly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_gpu.py", line 184, in <module>
    params, dataset, trainSet, validSet, modelDim, outPath, voicing, fftSize, seqNumber)
  File "/net/inavouable/u.anasynth/laffitte/Code/CNNforMelodyExtraction/modelLearning.py", line 188, in trainStatefull
    shuffle = False
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1426, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 191, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1214, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 797, in _standardize_user_data
    sample_weight, feed_output_names)
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 198, in standardize_sample_weights
    'sample_weight')
  File "/u/formes/share/packages/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 157, in standardize_sample_or_class_weights
    if x_weight is None or len(x_weight) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

There must be an issue with my generator since it works fine when I use a "dummy" generator, but I can't get my head around what the error might be, especially with this cryptic error message.

Comment: What are you providing as `class_weight=` for the `fit_generator` function? Do you mind posting some code?

Comment: When you ask questions here, it's _really_ helpful (and would probably get you an answer faster) if you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)): just a starting point for the people here that want to help you. This way we can just copy/paste the code and go straight into solving the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you really did to produce this result.